# Access Gyroscope from WebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview, gyroscope

I'm trying to access the Gyroscope in a WebView in Swift 2, on iOS. This is used by Javascript in a WebView. It works perfectly well in Safari, but doesn't seem to in the WebView - is there a way that I can pass the Gyroscope data? It's confusing me a little, as it works fine in Safari.

The Javascript which is accessing the Gyro is KRPano (KRPano.com), which was included in an export from Kolor Panotour Pro - just in case the gives any context!

It's really quite frustrating - all help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: do you know that you can hook into the gyroscope? why not access directly outside of the webview?

Comment: @JohnnyRockex Sorry, I don't quite understand!  I know that I can access the gyroscope natively but I need to access it from a web page inside the webview.

Comment: there's no way you can go outside the webview, i.e. use native code? This is a hybrid you don't have control over?

Comment: Sadly not, I really wish it didn't have to go this direction! It's a tricky one, I just can't seem to figure how on earth to make the gyro data accessible from the UIWebView...

Comment: I'm not sure if you can, I've never seen it. Perhaps look up location-based services from web-apps, *maybe* something is exposed, but I doubt it.